# What is difference if I don't use the else condition

Tags: c#

What is difference between these two examples:

```
if(firstchek)
{
    if(second)
    {
     return here();
    }
    else
    {
    return here();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
if(firstcheck)
{
    if(second)
    {
     return here();
    }
      return here();
    // else code without else
}
// code without else
// else code is here 
     return here();
```

Comment: If all you do is `return`, there is no difference. On the second snippet you have code *after the `if`* - that doesn't seem connected to your question.

Comment: i thing it too because when i run both command i not find any difference.

Comment: You could also do `return second ? here() : here();` if you're feeling especially tricky.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    foo();
    return;
}
bar();
return;
```

is the same as this:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    foo();
}
else
{
    bar();
}
return;
```

The only difference is in readability. Sometimes one way is more readable, sometimes the other. See [Refactoring: Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

**Nested conditionals**:

```
double getPayAmount() {
    double result;
    if (_isDead) result = deadAmount();
    else {
        if (_isSeparated) result = separatedAmount();
        else {
            if (_isRetired) result = retiredAmount();
            else result = normalPayAmount();
        };
    }
    return result;
};
```

**Guard clauses**:

```
double getPayAmount() {
    if (_isDead) return deadAmount();
    if (_isSeparated) return separatedAmount();
    if (_isRetired) return retiredAmount();
    return normalPayAmount();
};
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was edited after I posted my answer. I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no other code, there is no difference in terms of code paths and what gets executed.

The main difference, in general, is that when specifying an `else` clause, this will only run if the expression in the `if` evaluates to false. If you do not specify it, the code will *always* run.

**Update**:

This:

```
if(second)
{
 return here();
}
else
{
return here();
}
```

And this:

```
if(second)
{
 return here();
}
return here();
```

Would be the same as this:

```
return here();
```

Why? Because you are doing the same thing regardless of what `second` evaluates to, so the check is superfluous.

Comment: Technically you're correct, but thats a bit misleading because of the comment // else code without else

Comment: please tell me about if i only return not doing any action

Comment: @4thpage - if the updated examples are what you mean, then the two are **not** identical, because the first one will not return if `firstCheck` is false.

Comment: Good answer, although it became obsolete with the the update.

Answer (score 1):

The two sets of code are semantically similar. That is to say they will perform the same at run time. However, Whether you should use one form or another depends on the situation. Your code should express your intent in addition to the required semantics.

If the intent of the code is to do one or the other then keep the else so your intent is explicit. E.g.

```
if (withdrawAmmount < accountBalance)
{
    return Deduct();
}
else
{
    return ArrangeCredit();
}
```

If however the intent is to do the first thing in a special case then feel free to omit the else. E.g.

```
if (parameter == null)
{
    return NothingToDo();
}

return PerformActions();
```

For maintainability you should consider whether removing the return statements will change the behaviour and code on the basis that some idiot will do that (it could be me).

It should also be noted that with the else the code performs the same without the returns but without the returns omitting the else will cause the code to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

With the first code you are running something regardless if second is a defined value or not. It just depends on whether it is a defined value or not. If it is you run one bit of code. If it isn't then you run another. With the second example you will only run code if second is a defined value.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the else part is **only** executed if the second variable is false. 
In the second case, the part where the else is left out is always executed (given that firstcheck is true in both cases).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has too many return statements that i feel as repetitive for example

```
if(firstchek) 
{ 
    if(second) 
    { 
     return here(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    return here(); 
    } 
}
```

the above is equal to

```
if(firstchek) 
{         
   return here();         
}
```

because here() is the same function call. And the second example

```
 if(firstcheck)     
    {     
        if(second)     
        {     
         return here();     
        }     
          return here();     
        // else code without else     
    }     
    // code without else     
    // else code is here      
         return here();
```

is equal to

```
if(firstcheck)     
{     
   return here();     
}
 return here();
```

In the first example if there are some statement after the example and the top level if condition fails then the statements following  it will be executed example

```
 if(firstchek) 
    { 
        if(second) 
        { 
         return here(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
        return here(); 
        } 
    } 

CallMyCellNo();
```

CallMyCellNo() will be called if the toplevel if condition fails.

In the second example you have return here() after the toplevel if statement so regardless of the if condition's return value the function execution will terminate.